# How to fix Error 500 when I deploy on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, http-status-code-500

I created an application in Ruby on Rails, and everything is OK on my localhost but it doesn't work on Heroku:

```
We’re sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

At the beginning, I had a problem with the database, which was not PostgreSQL, but I fixed the problem.

When I check the logs and can see the problem is:

```
2020-03-28T12:38:29.235789+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=olivier-godard.herokuapp.com request_id=840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d fwd="37.120.204.164" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
```

I tried `db:migrate`, then `heroku push master` again.

```
2020-03-28T12:34:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user projet.site.2015@gmail.com
2020-03-28T12:35:55.952108+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 930a6879 by user projet.site.2015@gmail.com
2020-03-28T12:35:55.952108+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user projet.site.2015@gmail.com
2020-03-28T12:35:57.080831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-03-28T12:35:57.375779+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-03-28T12:35:58.799290+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2020-03-28T12:35:58.801702+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2020-03-28 12:35:58 +0000 ===
2020-03-28T12:35:58.801704+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2020-03-28T12:35:58.801705+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2020-03-28T12:36:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-03-28T12:36:08.781105+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2020-03-28T12:36:08.781123+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 6.0.2.1 application starting in production
2020-03-28T12:36:08.781124+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
2020-03-28T12:36:10.110905+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-03-28T12:36:09.871297+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2020-03-28T12:36:09.871326+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Mysterious Traveller
2020-03-28T12:36:09.871327+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2020-03-28T12:36:09.871327+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2020-03-28T12:36:09.871639+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:16317
2020-03-28T12:36:09.872016+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2020-03-28T12:38:29.235789+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=olivier-godard.herokuapp.com request_id=840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d fwd="37.120.204.164" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2020-03-28T12:38:29.222883+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:38:29.222773 #4]  INFO -- : [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d] Started GET "/" for 37.120.204.164 at 2020-03-28 12:38:29 +0000
2020-03-28T12:38:29.225673+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:38:29.225603 #4]  INFO -- : [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d] Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2020-03-28T12:38:29.231929+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:38:29.231848 #4]  INFO -- : [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d]   Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
2020-03-28T12:38:29.233977+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:38:29.233904 #4]  INFO -- : [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d]   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 248)
2020-03-28T12:38:29.234403+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:38:29.234329 #4]  INFO -- : [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d]   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.4ms | Allocations: 1253)
2020-03-28T12:38:29.234656+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:38:29.234595 #4]  INFO -- : [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (Allocations: 2442)
2020-03-28T12:38:29.235754+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-03-28T12:38:29.235690 #4] FATAL -- : [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d]
2020-03-28T12:38:29.235754+00:00 app[web.1]: [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d] ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "data_1" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
2020-03-28T12:38:29.235755+00:00 app[web.1]: [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d]     10:     </div>
2020-03-28T12:38:29.235756+00:00 app[web.1]: [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d]     11:   </div>
2020-03-28T12:38:29.235756+00:00 app[web.1]: [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d]     12:   <div class="bloc-image">
2020-03-28T12:38:29.235757+00:00 app[web.1]: [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d]     13:     <%= image_tag 'data_1', class: "image-svg" %>
2020-03-28T12:38:29.235757+00:00 app[web.1]: [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d]     14:   </div>
2020-03-28T12:38:29.235758+00:00 app[web.1]: [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d]     15:   <div id="presentation">
2020-03-28T12:38:29.235758+00:00 app[web.1]: [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d]     16:     <div class="bloc-presentation">
2020-03-28T12:38:29.235759+00:00 app[web.1]: [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d]
2020-03-28T12:38:29.235759+00:00 app[web.1]: [840fbcb6-1f17-47f0-9d83-23318df3374d] app/views/pages/home.html.erb:13
2020-03-28T12:38:29.725103+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=olivier-godard.herokuapp.com request_id=6212842c-bbdb-438f-9d86-5515322c140f fwd="37.120.204.164" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
2020-03-28T12:39:41.252676+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by user projet.site.2015@gmail.com
2020-03-28T12:39:49.767859+00:00 heroku[run.7053]: State changed from starting to up
2020-03-28T12:39:58.708611+00:00 heroku[run.7053]: State changed from up to complete
2020-03-28T12:40:12.950852+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=olivier-godard.herokuapp.com request_id=63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197 fwd="37.120.204.164" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2020-03-28T12:40:12.944252+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:40:12.944150 #4]  INFO -- : [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197] Started GET "/" for 37.120.204.164 at 2020-03-28 12:40:12 +0000
2020-03-28T12:40:12.944998+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:40:12.944934 #4]  INFO -- : [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197] Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2020-03-28T12:40:12.945750+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:40:12.945692 #4]  INFO -- : [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197]   Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
2020-03-28T12:40:12.946106+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:40:12.946054 #4]  INFO -- : [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197]   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 61)
2020-03-28T12:40:12.946464+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:40:12.946413 #4]  INFO -- : [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197]   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 273)
2020-03-28T12:40:12.946616+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:40:12.946565 #4]  INFO -- : [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (Allocations: 593)
2020-03-28T12:40:12.947553+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-03-28T12:40:12.947494 #4] FATAL -- : [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197]
2020-03-28T12:40:12.947554+00:00 app[web.1]: [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197] ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "data_1" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
2020-03-28T12:40:12.947554+00:00 app[web.1]: [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197]     10:     </div>
2020-03-28T12:40:12.947554+00:00 app[web.1]: [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197]     11:   </div>
2020-03-28T12:40:12.947555+00:00 app[web.1]: [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197]     12:   <div class="bloc-image">
2020-03-28T12:40:12.947555+00:00 app[web.1]: [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197]     13:     <%= image_tag 'data_1', class: "image-svg" %>
2020-03-28T12:40:12.947556+00:00 app[web.1]: [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197]     14:   </div>
2020-03-28T12:40:12.947556+00:00 app[web.1]: [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197]     15:   <div id="presentation">
2020-03-28T12:40:12.947556+00:00 app[web.1]: [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197]     16:     <div class="bloc-presentation">
2020-03-28T12:40:12.947557+00:00 app[web.1]: [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197]
2020-03-28T12:40:12.947557+00:00 app[web.1]: [63685b73-070a-4b79-89a2-be5a41dc6197] app/views/pages/home.html.erb:13
2020-03-28T12:40:13.363954+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=olivier-godard.herokuapp.com request_id=bf6a8a8f-e44c-4fd9-987a-5112f0abe117 fwd="37.120.204.164" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2020-03-28T12:40:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user projet.site.2015@gmail.com
2020-03-28T12:42:34.099779+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user projet.site.2015@gmail.com
2020-03-28T12:42:34.099779+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7f608ab3 by user projet.site.2015@gmail.com
2020-03-28T12:42:35.818867+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-03-28T12:42:35.896985+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-03-28T12:42:36.945354+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2020-03-28T12:42:36.945876+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2020-03-28 12:42:36 +0000 ===
2020-03-28T12:42:36.945908+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2020-03-28T12:42:36.946038+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2020-03-28T12:42:41.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-03-28T12:42:58.009374+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2020-03-28T12:42:58.009404+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 6.0.2.1 application starting in production
2020-03-28T12:42:58.009405+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
2020-03-28T12:43:00.239967+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-03-28T12:43:00.025594+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2020-03-28T12:43:00.025627+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Mysterious Traveller
2020-03-28T12:43:00.025628+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2020-03-28T12:43:00.025628+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2020-03-28T12:43:00.025952+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:45616
2020-03-28T12:43:00.026326+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2020-03-28T12:44:43.389577+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:44:43.389449 #4]  INFO -- : [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af] Started GET "/" for 37.120.204.164 at 2020-03-28 12:44:43 +0000
2020-03-28T12:44:43.392427+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:44:43.392363 #4]  INFO -- : [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af] Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2020-03-28T12:44:43.402094+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:44:43.401999 #4]  INFO -- : [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af]   Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
2020-03-28T12:44:43.405439+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:44:43.405351 #4]  INFO -- : [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af]   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 248)
2020-03-28T12:44:43.406306+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:44:43.406204 #4]  INFO -- : [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af]   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 4.0ms | Allocations: 1253)
2020-03-28T12:44:43.406670+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-28T12:44:43.406575 #4]  INFO -- : [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (Allocations: 2442)
2020-03-28T12:44:43.407830+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-03-28T12:44:43.407758 #4] FATAL -- : [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af]
2020-03-28T12:44:43.407831+00:00 app[web.1]: [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af] ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "data_1" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
2020-03-28T12:44:43.407832+00:00 app[web.1]: [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af]     10:     </div>
2020-03-28T12:44:43.407832+00:00 app[web.1]: [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af]     11:   </div>
2020-03-28T12:44:43.407834+00:00 app[web.1]: [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af]     12:   <div class="bloc-image">
2020-03-28T12:44:43.407848+00:00 app[web.1]: [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af]     13:     <%= image_tag 'data_1', class: "image-svg" %>
2020-03-28T12:44:43.407848+00:00 app[web.1]: [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af]     14:   </div>
2020-03-28T12:44:43.407849+00:00 app[web.1]: [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af]     15:   <div id="presentation">
2020-03-28T12:44:43.407849+00:00 app[web.1]: [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af]     16:     <div class="bloc-presentation">
2020-03-28T12:44:43.407850+00:00 app[web.1]: [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af]
2020-03-28T12:44:43.407851+00:00 app[web.1]: [69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af] app/views/pages/home.html.erb:13
2020-03-28T12:44:43.410088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=olivier-godard.herokuapp.com request_id=69de93ec-c402-4332-b7ff-25992a45d6af fwd="37.120.204.164" dyno=web.1 connect=32ms service=29ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2020-03-28T12:44:43.958483+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=olivier-godard.herokuapp.com request_id=e89ec38b-151b-4324-bd42-5fea9a706326 fwd="37.120.204.164" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
```

I don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: Did you check https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline#missing-asset-in-precompile-list

Answer (score 0):

At the very end of your logs, you can see the error. It is a bit hard to read with all the extra information, but I extracted it for you.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "data_1" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
10:     </div>
11:   </div>
12:   <div class="bloc-image">
13:     <%= image_tag 'data_1', class: "image-svg" %>
14:   </div>
15:   <div id="presentation">
16:     <div class="bloc-presentation">

app/views/pages/home.html.erb:13
```

On heroku, the `image_tag`s don't work, if you don't give the file extension for the picture. (It does work on localhost, so that is why you didn't catch it earlier).

So here, just change the file extension, so that it is like this (with `jpg` or `svg` or whatever it is).

`<%= image_tag 'data_1.svg', class: "image-svg" %>`

Comment: I had the same problem but the issue was that image filename changed case which Github/Heroku  did not pick up.